# How does the Angel Beats special episode connect with the main storyline?

Tags: angel-beats

In the special episode (Stairway to Heaven), the Battlefront has decided to commence a new mission: Operation High Tension Syndrome.

How is this story connected to the main timeline of the anime? Or do they have completely different and unrelated stories? Is this special episode considered canon?

Comment: It's pretty much just a filler episode. It's just meant to be a completely pointless, fun, yet over the top, and a little odd sort of break from the main story.

Answer (score 1):

The OVA is actually set between episodes 4 and 5 of the series. It's part of the main timeline, but it doesn't really have any effect on the overarching plot.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Angel_Beats!_episodes